# JS - Style Change Issue

Tags: javascript

Having an issue with my script, Its meant to show a button if it gets into the `ELSE` meaning if the Season Episode name isnt found then show the button, But for some reason it always shows it once I change my  tag's value. It's meant to only show if its not a value that can be found.

JS:

```
function season1episodesChange() {

    var s1_episodes = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('s1_episodes').value);

    var selectseason1episode = document.getElementById('selectseason1episode');

    for (var i = 1; i <= s1_episodes.length; i++){
        if (selectseason1episode.value == s1_episodes[i - 1]){
            document.getElementById('season1episode' + i).style.display = 'inline-block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(['season1episode' + i].join('')).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('notuploadedyet').style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }

}
```

Update:

Tried adding:

```
document.getElementById('notuploadedyet').style.display = 'none';
```

In the `if {}` bit but now it seems to only hide when im on the last value or first value it will open and stay open in all other values.

Comment: You are joining on the else statement and not joining to select the element in the first condition. Can you log this element to see if it exists `document.getElementById(['season1episode' + i].join(''))`

Comment: When there is no button (Cause theres no episodename for it) then it says it cant read style properties of null which is expected since my PHP only egenrtes a season1episode(X) button when its actually there when theres a episodename for it.

Comment: The button is `notuploadedyet` right? it seems you never hide it before check, so once it appears, it never hides again. Also, unless all item in `s1_episodes` have same value, your for loop with eventually comes to `else` statement, which means it'll show the `notuploadedyet` anyway(if there's more than 1 item).

Comment: No it's set to Display: None by the default html. If I do onpageload=season1episodeschange()" and reload the page it will show the first buttonwith a episodename withouth showing the not uploaded button if I then click on the episodechanger select tag and change its value to idk episode 2 or 3 (They too have an episodename) it will then show the button and never hide it again.

Comment: I do see what you mean with your updated comment but how would I go around this then?

Comment: That's what I mean, once you show it, there's no code to hide it, at least in the code you post.

Comment: So I should add a hide in the if and then a show in the else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the discussion, the logic is:

Loop through the possible options value, then:

1. Hide all not matched elements.
2. If no element match, show `notuploaded` button.
3. If an element match, show the episode if it exist, otherwise, show `notupload` button, so the code can be:

```
function season3episodesChange() {
    var s1_episodes = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('s1_episodes').value);
    var selectseason3episode = document.getElementById('selectseason3episode');

    //Setup the Flag.
    var notuploaded = true;
    var targetEle;

    for (var i = 1; i <= s1_episodes.length; i++){
        // Get the element to show first.
        targetEle = document.getElementById('season3episode' + i);

        // Only check match if the element to match exist
        // So even if it match, it won't see notuploaded to false.
        if (targetEle !== null) {
           if (selectseason3episode.value == s1_episodes[i - 1]){
                document.getElementById('season3episode' + i).style.display = 'inline-block';

                // Hide the button when : there's exist an element which match the select.
                notuploaded = false;
            } else {
                // Hide the not matched but exist elements.
                document.getElementById(['season3episode' + i].join('')).style.display = 'none';
            }   
        }
    }

    //Using the flag decide to show the notuploaded button or not;
    document.getElementById('notuploadedyet').style.display = notuploaded ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: Yes it creates a JSONencoded array and then parses it. But it adds it to a input tag is there a way to put it straight into the JS? The jsonencoded array is being output by the php doe as its being grabbed from a Database.

Comment: document.getElementById(['season3episode' + i].join('')).style.display = 'none'; in the else is giving me a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null but thats because there is no button for it. So I dont really need the Else :P

Comment: It still doesnt seem to show the button :/, It stays hidden now

Comment: Is your site public, I'd like to see how it looks then, not easy to tell what the issue maybe without an example. And somehow, why there's `season3episode`? your code seems to produce `season1episode` + X only.

Comment: Dont want to publicly give it out on here. But click here: http://pastebin.com/uLsYgtQG

Comment: I have 3 functions with this same code just different seasons :)

Comment: Found the issue, Im stupid, All the episode names are in the input tag's value evn if thres no button outputted by PHP. Is there a way to check for a button tags id and if its there then it will show it, If its not found then we can just show the not uploaded button

Comment: Yes, I was about to ask you why epsiode 3 is incomplete :), but let me ask something first, is the episodes previously selected keep displaying is what you expect, or there should only have one episode remains?

Comment: So is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can first use `var target  = document.getElementById(xxx);` and if the element is not exist, `target` will be `null`, so if its null, show not uploaded yet, otherwise, show episode.

Comment: I need it to be like doing this automatically with the i thing as a condition instead of if (selectseason3episode.value == s3_episodes[i - 1]){ because thats whats screwing this up cause it has all S3 episodenames even with no buttons, So how can I get it to instead of that if condition have it check some otherway wich button should be showed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89837/discussion-between-fuyushimoya-and-john123).